# Form/PHP and MySQL, unsure if updates are correctly done.

Tags: php, html, mysql

very new to HTML and PHP and extremely new to MySQL
I have a form on my website an require the information inputted to be stored in a database and emailed to myself. However I am not 100% sure what I am missing in the PHP code and whether or not my database is set up correctly.

Form HTML Code:

```
<form action="review.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Your Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Name" name="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    Please select Product:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--Product Drop Down Box-->
                        <select name="product">
                        <option value="weddingdress">Wedding Dress Alteration</option>
                        <option value="promdress">Prom Dress Alteration</option>
                        <option value="eveningdress">Evening Dress Alteration</option>
                        <option value="coat">Coat/Jacket Alteration</option>
                        <option value="jeans">Jeans Alteration</option>
                        <option value="trouser">Trouser Alteration</option>
                        <option value="suittrouser">Suit Trouser Alteration</option>
                        <option value="suitjacket">Suit Jacket Alteration</option>
                        <option value="fullsuit">Full Suit Alteration</option>
                        <option value="zip">Zip Repair/Addition</option>
                        <option value="button">Button Repair/Addition</option>
                        <option value="curtains">Curtain Alteration</option>
                        </select><br>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    Your Comment:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Comment" name="comment" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <br><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Review" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];


$host="host";
$user_name="username";
$pwd="password";
$database_name="db_name";
$db=mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd);
if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);
if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
?>
```

and a screenshot of my table inside database can be seen at:
[image]

All help is greatly appreciated

php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

is the error I am receiving

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing, and what is your question? I don't see an actual question here. P.S. I hope you did not just post your actual database username and password. If you did, edit them out immediately.

Comment: .. and change your DB password too. (Stackoverflow has revisions)

Comment: I've edited his details out.

Comment: Now change your password

Comment: I havent tested it as I assumed I would have to tell it what table to store it in?

Comment: and thanks for changing my details

Comment: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: Typically databases use a variety of other fields to contextualize the information. So aside from your core data here - name, product, comment - you'll want a field called ID which gives each row a unique ID number and allows you to find data (set that field to Primary Key, Auto Increment). Otherwise, it's difficult to locate specifics rows of data. You may also want other fields like date_created, ip_address, etc...

Comment: thats great, how do I change the primary keY?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a lack of any proper question, the only suggestion I can offer for you is to not use any mysql_ PHP functions, as they are deprecated and will be phased out, in part due to security reasons. You will want to use PDO instead to bridge the gap between PHP and SQL. For instance:

```
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=database','username','password');
```

This should be self explanatory here. Your details are placed in the relevant areas. You can see how this is also simplified into one line for connecting and selecting a database.

You can read up about PDO [here](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Thanks, do I need to point the php to my table within the database?

Comment: Not sure I understood that question, but this should hopefully answer everything with examples and comparisons to how the old mysql_ method worked, and how it currently works in PDO: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Running_Simple_Select_Statements

Comment: Sorry if i seem dumb, complete beginner and appreciate links to tutorials.  The form is on review.html, which actions to review.php (in which I have include the POST's and have put in the PDO link you suggested and inputted my mysql details). When I run it I get a blank screen, which I assume is good news as I havent given it a return url yet. My question is, where do I tell the php to send the info to 'reviewform' table on my database, as when I refresh phpadmin, it returns zero rows? Thanks

Comment: Again, I'll refer you to the same page, but a different section, as it could probably explain it better than I can: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#INSERT.2C_DELETE.2C_UPDATE_Prepared_Queries This should give you some examples of how to use variables you have already defined, and insert them into rows in your table. As you can see, the syntax for using SQL is still the same. It's just the PHP parts that look different.